# How do I receive the file on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, file-upload

I have a code like this in my local exe to upload a file in a certain url:

```
    private static void SaveTToWeb()
    {
        try {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.UploadFile("www.something.com/uploadreceiver.aspx", "POST", "text.txt");
            client.Dispose();
            myFile = null;
            urlForUpload = null;
        }
        catch (Exception err) { Console.write("error: " + err.Message(); }
    }
```

my question is, in the server side "uploadreceiver.aspx" page, what code should i use to actually receive the file? thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? If you're sending to a web server, then typically the file data is contained in the `Request.Files` collection.

Comment: @StealthOne : did you get workaround the same? If yes, please share it so that it would be helpful for all

Answer (score 1):

The CSASPNETRemoteUploadAndDownload sample shows how to upload files to and download files from remote server in an ASP.NET application.

You can download the sample code or read more here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETRemoteUploadAndDown-a80b7cb5